# Docker Swarm with Traefik: containers are up but getting 404

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, docker-swarm-mode

I am struggling to get a Docker swarm stack set up using traefik. I decided to try traefik as an alternative to jwolder/nginx-proxy, as unfortunately the latter does not seem to support Docker swrarm mode. But I'm finding traefik to be a problem (probably my fault!).

I have a WordPress container (replicated) and a MySQL container, alongside the traefik container. All of the containers in the swarm are created and start, and `docker logs <container_id>` reveals no errors, but when I visit 'example.org' (not the real domain) I just see `404 page not found`. So it must be a communication issue between traefik and the containers I wish to proxy. However I also don't see the traefik dashboard, so perhaps soemthing else is going on.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api.insecure=true \
      --providers.docker=true \
      --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false \
      --providers.docker.swarmmode=true \
      --providers.docker.watch=true \
      --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - traefik
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - traefik
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root_password>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <db_name>
      MYSQL_USER: <db_user>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <user_password>
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3

  app:
    image: my-repo/wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - traefik
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.org
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.org"

networks:
  traefik:
```

The orignal nginx-proxy setup works nicely, but, as I say, won't allow me to run a swarm. I have been experimenting with traefik for only a day, so it's probably a schoolboy error of some kind.

N.B: I am aliasing my actual .org domain to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts. Perhaps that's an issue? I can't imagine it would be, I've been running Docker containers with that setup for ages without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I got it to work in non-swarm mode with the following docker-compose file:

version: '3'

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - traefik

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - traefik
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root_password>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <db_name>
      MYSQL_USER: <db_user>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <user_password>

  app:
    image: my-repo/wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`example.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=web"

networks:
  traefik:
```

And then I tried the following swarm configuration, which worked:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmmode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - traefik
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role==manager]

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - traefik
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root_password>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <db_name>
      MYSQL_USER: <db_user>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <user_password>
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3

  app:
    image: my-repo/wordpress:latest
    networks:
      - traefik
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`example.org`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

networks:
  traefik:
```

More specifically, I got it to work only after adding the command

```
- "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

and the proxied container label

```
- "traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

... so I'm not really sure what I did right. Would be grateful for any light that could be shed on that.

It's working now, though, at least.

**UPDATE**: The Traefik docs state that the label

```
traefik.http.services.<service_name>.loadbalancer.server.port
```

is [mandatory for Docker swarm mode](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/routing/providers/docker/) (look under **Services** on that page). So it seems as if I was just missing that.

Comment: ALLAH give you the best...You solved my 3 days tries! Thanks a lot

Comment: @MohsenAbasi Well thank you - although I have now largely moved away from Docker for my deployments, finding I was able to make good use of static site frameworks and serverless architecture. I'm glad someone found this info useful though.

Comment: I will be glad to learn your solutions. What is the link of your info on serverless arch?

Comment: @MohsenAbasi We migrated to Cloudflare Pages (Google that and it'll pop up first). I;m afraid I can;t provide any more info than that.